# A fellow employee keeps making false accusations against me - who can I contact for help?

Tags: intervention, harassment

I am getting accused of hitting, screaming and sabotage of personnel records.  Every day there is a new accusation.  I have been investigated by HR who found that the accusations have no basis.  Still, she continues to make new accusations against me.  What can I do?

Comment: Have you asked your HR what you can do about these false allegations?  Are you sure you need to do anything?

Comment: I am tired of being falsely accused and investigated by HR. I've talked to HR about this and was told that they are trying to figure out a solution. In the meantime, I am afraid that it will escalate to another level with her because she is not getting the response from HR that she wants - which is to get rid of me and give her my job! I feel like I'm in a Lifetime TV movie, "The Crazy Coworker"

Comment: I'm going to try and formulate a clearer response to this, but for now just don't retaliate and play everything by the book.  I assure you that is best for everyone.

Comment: Have you filed a formal harassment complaint with HR? You don't want everything in your record to just be complaints against you.

Comment: If HR is working on a solution then for the most part the ball is out of your court.  Document everything, don't engage, keep your distance.  Also keep on HR for updates as this is a high priority issue for your well being.

Comment: Raise a grievance your company does have a grievance procedure? Check your company handbook

Answer (score 8):

What you can do will depend on the country in which this is happening.

That being said, from an US perspective, this, as you are describing the issue right now, is workplace harassment. You need to go to HR immediately and state that you expect to find a way to settle this issue. If this continues or HR is not responsive to your request then you may want to get a lawyer involved to protect your rights.

HR, despite what it sounds like, is there to minimize the companies' liabilities. Sometimes this aligns nicely with protecting your rights, sometimes it doesn't. Constant, unfounded accusations will potentially make people think "Where there's smoke there's fire!" and may cause you problems.

Are you a member of a union? If yes get your union rep involved.
Is your manager aware of the situation? If no, get them involved. If yes talk to them - they should go to bat for you!

Your best solution to this issue is to be proactive and nip these complaints in the bud.

Answer (score 2):

How can you deal with this unacceptable behavior?

First: Keep a handwritten log of incidents. Mention date, time, offending utterance or action, and names of people witnessing it. Keep this log under your personal control at all times; don't leave it on your desk when you're not there, for example.

Second: Let your HR department, and your supervisor, know this is going on, and that it is affecting the quality of your work and your life. Ask them to intervene to put a stop to this behavior. Give them copies of your incident log. Never give them the original.

Third: Avoid being alone with this person in the absence of any witness. If necessary ask your supervisor and the HR department to make necessary changes to work assignments so you don't have to be alone with this person to do your job.

Fourth: You may (or may not) want to intervene with this person. You may, in the presence of a witness, want to say something like this:

> When you accuse me of striking you, it upsets me and damages my good name. Please stop saying that I struck you.

The formula is simple for such a statement of intervention.

1. Describe the behavior
2. Describe the effect of the behavior on you personally
3. Request a change in behavior

Understand that this person is not going to stop doing this immediately because you asked for the change.

Leave the rest to your HR department and supervisor. They will deal with it. This sort of behavior has no place in the workplace and they know it.

Comment: Do **not** ever allow yourself to be alone with the other person. Do whatever it takes. Walk out of whatever room you are in to one with other coworkers, etc. Going to the bathroom, see the other person (assuming same sex), turn around and hold it, or use another. Can't stress that enough.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if she keeps making accusations that don't pan out, HR will decide at some point that she is tying up their resources and make her a tough offer - something like "the next time that you make accusation that doesn't pan out against this person, it may be the last accusation that you'll be making while employed by this firm".

I wouldn't sweat it. She is digging a bigger hole for herself with every accusation of hers that she makes that doesn't pan out. The accusations she makes are each a fireable offense, if substantiated. Making unsubstantiated accusations about fireable offenses is a fireable offense. At this point, there is no disputing that she is disruptive both to you and to HR. As I said, she is digging a bigger hole for herself.

Make your supervisors and your co-workers, if friendly, aware of what she is doing. I once got out from an accusation of sexual harassment by a third party when I pointed out that at no time during each workday was I ever alone with the alleged victim. To the extent you can, make sure that you have witnesses who can back you up. If she persists, she will most likely self-destruct.

These references might help you:

[Be Zen and don't get in the way of an HR investigation that's going to clear you and get at the culprit](http://flourishanyway.hubpages.com/hub/Accused-of-Wrongdoing-At-Work-What-To-Do)

Typical company policy handbook: "[An employee who intentionally files a report of wrongdoing will be subject to disciplinary action, up and including termination](https://secure.ethicspoint.com/domain/media/en/gui/10935/Standards.pdf)"

Another typical employee handbook: [Making accusations which are known by the accusing person to be false is a form of misconduct which will likely result in serious impairment of the university's efforts to administer this policy properly and effectively for the benefit of all employees. Accordingly, such misconduct will result in disciplinary action up to and including termination.](http://www.armstrong.edu/departments/human_resources/human_resources_employee_handbook)

Answer (score 0):

> Still, she continues to make new accusations against me. What can I
>   do?

You could simply choose to ignore the accusations from someone who has no basis for them.

Or you could again talk with HR, and ask how you and they together can get them stopped.